# How would I dynamically add the right amount of cells and display videos in them

Tags: swift, uiview, uiscrollview, avplayer, swift5

At the moment I have a swift file where I have three hardcoded values using a datamodel I also created that takes a title, image and url (I'm only showing the image at the moment). I understand how to change each cell to show its respective image that it should show in the scrollview:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import Firebase

struct CustomData {
var title: String
var image: UIImage
var url: String
}

var videoURL = ""
var array = [String]()

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

var fileArray:Array<Any>?

fileprivate let data = [
    CustomData(title: "Test", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ss-1"), url: "test.com"),
    CustomData(title: "Test2", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "done-button"), url: "test.com"),
    CustomData(title: "Test2", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "notificationIcon"), url: "test.com")
]

fileprivate let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cv.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    return cv
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(collectionView)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 150).isActive = true
    collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
    collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
    collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true 

    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self

    array = fileArray as! [String]
}
}

extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource{

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: collectionView.frame.width)
}
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.data = self.data[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
}

class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell{

var data: CustomData?{
    didSet{
        guard let data = data else { return }
        bg.image = data.image
    }
}

fileprivate let bg: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "splash_icon")
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    iv.clipsToBounds = true
    iv.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    return iv
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    //        let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: videoURL)!)
    //        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    //        playerLayer.frame = contentView.bounds
    //        contentView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    //        player.play()

    contentView.addSubview(bg)
    bg.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    bg.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    bg.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    bg.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

The code above successfully shows all the three images I specified in the `data` array in the scroll view in their respective cell. 
I have an array that holds 10 strings which are all unique urls locally on the device to different videos (all of the same size). I have managed to display a video by changing this part:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
super.init(frame: frame)

//        let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: videoURL)!)
//        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
//        playerLayer.frame = contentView.bounds
//        contentView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
//        player.play()

contentView.addSubview(bg)
bg.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
bg.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
bg.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
bg.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

to this:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
super.init(frame: frame)

let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: videoURL)!)
let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
playerLayer.frame = contentView.bounds
contentView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
player.play()

//        contentView.addSubview(bg)
//        bg.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
//        bg.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
//        bg.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
//        bg.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

but that obviously hardcodes in one video and that same video will be shown on all of the cells in the scroll view. So how would I do the same as I did with the UIImageView:

```
var data: CustomData?{
didSet{
    guard let data = data else { return }
    bg.image = data.image
}
}

fileprivate let bg: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "splash_icon")
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    iv.clipsToBounds = true
    iv.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    return iv
}()
```

but with AVPlayer or some other video player to make all the cells dynamically show the different videos, I know I'll have to change the datamodel and get values from the array etc, I just can't seem to find a way to do the same as I did with the image view.

Thanks,

Nathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at your codes, you managed to get the images showing as you wanted because of this codeblock where you are setting `data.image` into your `UIImageView`

```
var data: CustomData?{
    didSet{
        guard let data = data else { return }
        bg.image = data.image
    }
}
```

If you want to play the videos listed in your `data` for each cell, you will need to initialize the AVP player with `data.url`.

Not wanting to mess up too much of your code, what you can try is this:

```
 override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

      // only create the player if the data.url is present AND is a valid URL instead of just a bunch of normal text
      if let unwrappedURLString = data?.url, let url = URL(string: unwrappedURLString) {
        let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.frame = contentView.bounds
        contentView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        player.play()
      }
    }
```

even if you wanted to initialize this like your UIImageView like this, there are still a lot of issues to address and errors to handle when compiling

```
fileprivate let player: AVPlayer = {
    let dataURL = data?.url ?? "random URL" // this will not compile because data is an instance variable which will not be available when this AVP player is initialized on memory load
    let url = URL(string: initialURL) // this line will still produce an optional URL so you need to also handle the unwrapping issue when you construct the URL here
    let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
    return player
  }()
```

Comment: I tried that but swift won't let me reference the data.url in the data model since I had to unwrap it first, if that makes sense, I could Update my question a bit more for some more info, thank you so much for the reply though!

Comment: I need to do the same as I did with `fileprivate let bg: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "splash_icon")
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    iv.clipsToBounds = true
    iv.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    return iv
}()` to reference anything in that codeblock.

Comment: Yeah, but what would happen if your URL was `nil` though? Is it still supposed to display the AVP Player?

However, if you initialize it like your UIImageView, it will ALWAYS create an AVP player regardless if you need it or if there is no URL, which might lead so some memory leaks especially in a tableview. My advice is to unwrap the data in the init function and then decide if you want to create it.

I have edited my answer to reflect unwrapping the data.

Comment: Ill try that then, two seconds

Comment: I still need to be able to reference the fileprivate class in my customdata 'data' function to assign the variabled, which I cannot do until I reference it like I did the the fileprivate let bg: UIImageView

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59594656/how-to-reference-video-in-custom-data-model-for-avplayer

Comment: Why would you need to create a fileprivate class like the UIImageView though? You will not be able to access `data` in the CustomCell anyhow. your UIImageview initialization does not acecss the `data` variable within the CustomCell as well. The image only gets changed from splash_icon to proper image at the didSet { bg.image = data.image } block

Comment: that's what I'm Confused about I managed to get it to work with the image, which I want to replace with videos instead and the whole thing is so much harder, all I needed it to unwrap the data that I give in an array with all the local urls pointing towards their respective videos and for that to fill the scrollview in the same way the images are, If I try and set the video from data.url in your answer then all of the cells in the scoll view will be the same video.

Comment: the image replacement is straight forward because it data.image does not produce a nil value where as so bg.image = data.image does the magic for you

in order to do the same for your video, you can't just player.url = URL(string: data.url) because this will produce an optional.

if the videos are all the same for the cells, then wouldn't it be wiser to change the videos at `cellForItemAtIndexPath` delegate method instead of setting those data at memory load?

Comment: the videos were all the same by accident, I have different local urls to videos that's in my data model, all the videos are supposed to be different. I'm currently trying that then...

Comment: After a lot of head banging, a snippet of your code to unwrap the string worked, thank you!

Comment: Glad you got it working! Thank you and all the best!