# How to reference video in custom data model for AVPlayer

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, avplayer, swift5

I've managed to reference images for my custom data model which is used to show unique cells their different information. I've been able to do it for images, as it's a lot easier, I just have no clue how to do it for videos. My data model looks like this:

```
fileprivate let data = [
    CustomData(title: "Test", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ss-1"), url: "this-will-be-a-local-url-in-cache-to-a-video"),
    CustomData(title: "Test2", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "done-button"), url: "this-will-be-a-local-url-in-cache-to-a-video"),
    CustomData(title: "Test2", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "notificationIcon"), url: "this-will-be-a-local-url-in-cache-to-a-video")
]
```

and some of the most relevant code for the assigning the different information per cell in the scrollview:

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell{

var data: CustomData?{
    didSet{
        guard let data = data else { return }
        bg.image = data.image

    }
}

fileprivate let bg: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "splash_icon")
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    iv.clipsToBounds = true
    iv.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    return iv
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    contentView.addSubview(bg)
    bg.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    bg.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    bg.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    bg.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Now I know I need the same function as I used for images:

```
    fileprivate let bg: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "splash_icon")
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    iv.clipsToBounds = true
    iv.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    return iv
}()
```

Like this for videos, I just don't know how to reference the url some way in an AVPlayer function and reference it in the same way I did in my CustomData class:

```
    fileprivate let video: AVURLAsset = {

    }()
```

Thanks, please comment if you'd like more info, I've tired searching for what AVPlayer function allows me to do something like (AVPlayer.url = "URL") to assign the avplayer with the right url from the data model but obviously it's not that simple ahaha.

Nathan

EDIT:

What I'm asking is how would I achieve the same thing as I did in this image function:

```
 fileprivate let bg: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "splash_icon")
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    iv.clipsToBounds = true
    iv.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    return iv
}()
```

so I can reference it in the custom data class:

```
 var data: CustomData?{
    didSet{
        guard let data = data else { return }
        bg.image = data.image

    }
}
```

So it can unwrap the data from the custom data array for me to init it and show it in the view using this function:

```
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    contentView.addSubview(bg)
    bg.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    bg.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    bg.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    bg.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understood correctly your question, could you please tell me if my answer solves the problem that you described?

Comment: @RomanPodymov please see the information underneath the 'EDIT'

Comment: How do you declare `AVPlayer` instance?

Comment: @RomanPodymov thats what I'm trying to figure out, I don't know which one I should use yet]

Comment: Have you tried `AVPlayer.init(url:)`?

Comment: @RomanPodymov I think I've found a fix to that, it's just an issue with the uiscrollview now - I think, could you check my code in my new question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59626633/why-arent-my-videos-showing-in-cells-in-my-scroll-view-with-avplayer