# Why aren't my videos showing in cells in my scroll view with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionviewcell, avplayer

I know my code isn't efficient as of yet, I just want it to work really before I optimise it.

Basically I have a function `FeaturedPostsManager.shared.getFeaturedPosts` to get videos from my server and store it in the app's cache and store the local url to the video. Which in my code I do it twice for two different videos, so I have two urls that go to two different videos. I then add them urls in my custom data array for my scroll view to unwrap for each cell and add it's respective video to it's cell (eg. video one to cell one, video two to cell two) into an AVPlayer. No errors are thrown, it's just nothing is shown and this message is given to me:

```
The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2020-01-07 09:48:05.095012+0000 Clipify[9131:368986] the item height must be less than the 
height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the 
content insets top and bottom values.
2020-01-07 09:48:05.095574+0000 Clipify[9131:368986] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout 
instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7f8be8525c20>, and it is attached to 
<UICollectionView: 0x7f8be9063a00; frame = (16 150; 343 171.667); clipsToBounds = YES; 
gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600003f4c1e0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000319b100>; 
contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 0}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}; layout: 
<UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7f8be8525c20>; dataSource: <Clipify.HomeViewController: 
0x7f8be850c240>>.
```

I don't know if that means anything, but this is my full code:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import Firebase

struct CustomData {
    var title: String
    var image: UIImage
    var url: String
}

var videoURL = ""

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    var itemOne: String?
    var itemTwo: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(collectionView)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 150).isActive = true
    collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
    collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
    collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true 

    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self

    getPosts()
}

func getPosts(){
    FeaturedPostsManager.shared.getFeaturedPosts(index: 0, completion:  { url in
        if url != nil{
            self.itemOne = url!
            print(self.itemOne)
        }else{
            print("error")
        }
    })
    FeaturedPostsManager.shared.getFeaturedPosts(index: 1, completion:  { url in
        if url != nil{
            self.itemTwo = url!
            print(self.itemTwo)
        }else{
            print("error")
        }
    })
}

var data: [CustomData] {
    return [
        CustomData(title: "Test", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ss-1"), url: itemOne!),
        CustomData(title: "Test2", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "done-button"), url: itemTwo!)
    ]
}

fileprivate let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cv.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    return cv
}()
}

extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource{

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: collectionView.frame.width)
}
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.data = self.data[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
}

class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell{

    var data: CustomData?{
        didSet{
            guard let data = data else { return }
            bg.image = data.image
        }
    }

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    if let unwrappedURLString = data?.url, let url = URL(string: unwrappedURLString) {
        let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.frame = contentView.bounds
        contentView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        player.play()
    }
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the cells are visible? Try to display `UIImageView` with some image instead of `AVPlayerLayer`.

Comment: It works perfectly well when I use images, just not videos. So the scrollview and cells/data is all working perfectly well, it's just when I try and involve videos. I can show the code I used to show the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a reload here

```
FeaturedPostsManager.shared.getFeaturedPosts(index: 0, completion:  { url in
    if url != nil{
        self.itemOne = url!
        print(self.itemOne)
        DispatchQueue.main.async { self.collectionView.reloadData() }
    }else{
        print("error")
    }
})
FeaturedPostsManager.shared.getFeaturedPosts(index: 1, completion:  { url in
    if url != nil{
        self.itemTwo = url!
        print(self.itemTwo)
        DispatchQueue.main.async { self.collectionView.reloadData() }
    }else{
        print("error")
    }
})
```

`override init(frame: CGRect) {` is called once . so Add

```
func reload() {
 if let unwrappedURLString = data?.url, let url = URL(string: unwrappedURLString) {
    let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = contentView.bounds
    contentView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player.play()
 }
}
```

Then

```
var data: CustomData?{
    didSet{
        guard let data = data else { return }
        bg.image = data.image
        self.reload()
    }
}
```

Comment: that probably would've been another problem that I should've had, so thanks for that, but still didn't fix the issue, I think it's something to do with the data in the scroll view.

Comment: Nope, it successfully gets the url and prints out itemOne with a local url, so itemOne has a url string stored in it. Unless it stores the url after the scroll view is updated? I'm not even sure if that code will show the video in the scrollview cell.

Comment: that would be replacing the `override init(frame: CGRect) { ` which needs to be there for the scrollview is there any other way to reload it without replacing it with `reload(){}` ?

Comment: NeverMind! Just have two functions for it, that did the trick, thank you so much!